# Google URL Shortener - not specified HTTP Referer

Tags: php, google-api, url-shortener

I have URL shortening script the was working well until I added website referrers to KEY restriction in API console (which i had to do). Now i dosen't return short url. I get following error:

> Array ( [error] => Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [domain]
>   => usageLimits [reason] => ipRefererBlocked [message] => The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending
>   referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.
>   [extendedHelp] =>
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=XXXXXXXXX
>   ) ) [code] => 403 [message] => The request did not specify any
>   referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the
>   API Console to remove the referer restrictions. ) )

My PHP:

```
<?php

$longurl = "http://example.com";

$api_key_google = "XXXX_API_KEY_XXXXX";
$curl = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key='.$api_key_google);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('longUrl' => $longurl)));
$return = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
curl_close($curl);

print_r($return);       
echo $shortDWName = $return['id'];

?>
```

What Am I missing here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add this line

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// should add this line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '[your restriction domain]');
```